# Rails 3.2 - How to redirect to a namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, routes

In a Rails 3.2 application I'm doing I want to create some views (and action handling) specific for mobile devices. So I have created a namespace called mobile.

```
  namespace :mobile do
    resources :sessions
    resources :areas
  end
```

For example if the user goes to the login page with a mobile I want to use the controller and views I make for that namespace.

So now I have two different ways to login:

```
new_mobile_session GET    /mobile/sessions/new(.:format)      mobile/sessions#new
```

and

```
new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)             sessions#new
```

But when a requests comes how could I add the "mobile" namespace to the request if it comes from mobile?

I.e. changing /sessions/new into /mobile/sessions/new

I am using Rack::MobileDetect but I don't know how to use the redirect_to for that purpose.

```
config.middleware.use Rack::MobileDetect, :redirect_to => '/mobile'
```

Or should I use a different approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Try running rake:routes and see what you have, I imagine you need to redirect_to mobile_sessions_path or something along those lines.  If you don't have a mobile root no route would match /mobile

Answer (score 1):

You could use a constraint for that.
A Rails routing constraint either is class which responds to matches? or a lambda.

When a constraint is applied to a route, the route will only be considered if the constraint evaluates to true.

Consider this class

```
class MobileContraint
  def matches? request
     request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
  end
end
```

You can now use this class in the routes like this:

```
resources :sessions
resources :sessions, :controller=> 'mobile/sessions', :constraints => MobileConstraint.new
```